# How to share url between routers in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, routes, url-routing

I am building a backbone application, there are many modules so it should be complex to routing.

my routes are vary dynamic.

```
routes:{
   "groups":"groups",
   "groups/:gid/:section/:query": "accessApp"
},
accessApp:function(gid,mod,query){
    groups.selctGroup(gid);
    //query is dynamic url has several parts

   if(mod ==" task")
      //lets handle query by task router
   else( mod == "event")
       // handle query using events router

}
```

I would like to handle query with the respective router,

is it possible to handle some part of url with other router?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of the url parts like `groups/:section/:gid/:query` and then declare multiple routers :

```
// TaskRouter
routes: {
   "groups/task/:gid/:query": "yourFunction"
}

----------------------------------------------

// EventRouter
routes: {
   "groups/event/:gid/:query": "yourFunction"
}
```

and don't forget to instantiate all your routers :

```
new TaskRouter();
new EventRouter();
```